# Последовательные, комбинированные анимации

Tags: java, android

У меня есть несколько анимаций, допустим, пусть это будет вращение, затухание, появление, и потом перемещение.

Все эти анимации я хочу выполнить НЕ вместе, а по порядку, раздельно, последовательно...

Ищу Java класс, похожий чем-то на AnimationSet - т.е класс, где методами добавления анимации (например addAnimation()) и startAnimation(animationSet) можно запустить анимации последовательно.

Возможно, я многого с данной точки зрения хочу, но, если мне не изменяет память, то я точно помню, что такое класс существовал, но название я благополучно забыл.

Ну, и если вдруг до сих пор было не понятно, то анимации конфигурируются и запускаются из **Java** кода, НЕ xml

Конкретно, меня интересует замена всем слушателям окончания анимации, ибо чем их больше, тем плачевнее становится ситуация глобально.

Comment: Есть AnimationSet добавляйте туда сколько хотите анимаций. Есть для каждой анимации setDelay - задержка которая и позволяет делать последовательную анимацию.

Comment: @Style-7 мне не кажется, что данный способ будет лучшей практикой. У каждой анимации свой таймер, и как это внутри реализовано - интересно, но не очень. В любом случае, зависимость от времени - это ужасно на мой взгляд. Поэтому я предпочитаю стек обратных вызовов, который можно было бы реализовать самому, но ещё лучше юзать системные либы. Ну а так, да, способ вполне, рабочий, но не то

Comment: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/animations/prop-animation#choreography

Comment: еще можно ставить слушатели и по окончании одной анимации включать другую и т.п. Можно сделать свой собственный слушатель "универсальный" под свою задачу и т.п.